# Accessing fields of a string task returned from SQLite Database is giving errors

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

In my Xamarin application I have a local db set up using SQLite. I have followed the microsoft to-do list example when setting this up (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases) however I have hit an issue.

I have a model called "Animal" which is saved into my database and what I am trying to query the fields of:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set; }
    
    public string Species { get; set; }
  
    public string Markings { get; set; }
   
    public string Diet { get; set; }
```

Within my database query file I am trying to perform a query that will get the animal based upon it's name which is given by the user and then from this it will return its markings/diet/etc...
This is what I have so far but it is erroring and I am really not sure on how to fix it:

```
    public async Task<string> getanimaldiet(string name)
    {
        
            Animal a = Database.Table<Animal>().Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return a.Diet;


    }
```

Errors:
The name 'diet' does not exist in the current context & Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<animalService.Animal>' to 'animalService.Animal'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: The name 'diet' does not exist in the current context
& Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<animalService.Animal>' to 'animalService.Animal' updated post to include this

Answer (score 0):

Since you have async api you need to add await  to your code:

```
 Animal a =  await Database.Table<Animal>().Where(x => x.Name == name) 
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return a.Diet;
```

You can make it sync:

```
public string getanimaldiet(string name)
    {
      
Animal a =   Database.Table<Animal>().Where(x => x.Name == name) 
               .FirstOrDefault();

            return a.Diet;
)
```

Comment: Thank you! How would i then go about converting what is returned into a string rather than type System.threading.task.task?

Comment: use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefaultAsync`

Comment: Would i use that when I call the function in a different file @Jason?